# Incorporating round on a long formula

Tags: excel

I have the formula below that I would like to incorporate a round formula to 2 digits but cannot seem to get the syntax right.

Can someone help me on this?

=IFERROR(IF(G13<0,"",MIN(IFERROR(IF(G15>G14,"",PV(G12/12,240,G13-((C19+G13)-(C20*G14)))*-1)-1,""), (C9*90%-C10))),"")

Answer (score 0):

So use round() or roundup() or rounddown() as needed:

=round(your_formula,2)

Or add the round to the calculating parts only so round() is not applied to the blank result.